# What should be the dependencies of useEffect Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As it's said, the **useEffect** hook is the place where we do the ***side-effects*** related part. I'm having a confusion of what dependencies should be passed in the dependency array of **useEffect hook**?

The React documentation says

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders.

Consider an example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component mounted");
  }, []);


  const update = () => {
    for(let i=0; i<5;i++){
      setCount(count+i)
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
    {console.log(count)}
      {count}
      <button type="button" onClick={update}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Going with the above statement, ***we should pass the count variable as a dependency to useEffect***, it will make the **useEffect** re run.

But in the above example, not passing the **count** dependency doesn't create any problem with the UI. There is not stale value. The variable updates as expected, UI re-renders with exact value, logs the current value.

So my question is, why should we pass the **count** variable as dependency to **useEffect**. The UI is working correctly?

**UPDATE**

I know the useEffect callback is triggered everytime when the value in dependency array changes. My question is what should go in to the dependency array? Do we really need to pass state variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not implementing any logic inside useEffect that depends on count variable. without it dependencies or no dependencies, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: @DebarshiBhattacharjee if dependency is empty i.e [] then it will useEffect's callback only called one time, but is dependecy is mentioned in it then callback will be called every time dependency change.

Comment: Please read the updated part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To demonstrate and understand the issue print the count variable inside

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component updated ", count);
  }, []); // try to add it here
```

click again the button and see how it logs to the console

EDIT:
If you want to get notified by your IDE that you are missing dependencies then use this plugin
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin

Keep in mind that it will still complain if you want to simulate onMount

Comment: It's component mounted. I know the useEffect call back is triggered when the value in dependency array changes. My question is what go in to the dependency array? Should we really need to pass state variables?

Comment: If you want the useEffect function that you pass to be called only when mounted then yes keep it empty array. Otherwise if you want to call your function everytime then yes you should pass everything you used inside the function.

Comment: Yeah I know that. What I meant is how we decide what should go into the dependency array?

Comment: It is based on your needs, you can imagine it as if after every render all items in the array are compared to all the items provided on the previous render. If there is a difference between the items in the arrays (compared with ===) then the function is executed.

Comment: Okay understood. May be it was a silly question. But thanks for the answer. Cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

> **What should go into the dependency array?**

> Those things (**props/state**) that change over time and **that are used by the effect.**

In the example, the UI works correctly because ***setState*** re-renders the component.

But if we do some side-effect like calling an **alert** on change of `count`, we have to pass `count` to the dependency array. This will make sure the **callback** is called everytime the dependency (`count`) in our case, changes.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    alert(`Count ${count}`); // call everytime count changes
  }, [count]); // makes the callback run everytime, the count updates.
```

Answer (score 0):

If property from second argument in useEffect change - then component will rerender.

If you pass the count -> then component rerender after count change - one time.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component mounted");
  }, [count]);
```

Quick answer:

Pass everytime you need to trigger refreshing component.

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing component?

Comment: It's term in the scope of react lifecycles components - renew state - without refreshing page - after userinteraction

Answer (score -1):

useEffect will get called in an infinite loop unless you give it dependencies.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Looped endlessly");
}); // dependencies parameter missing
```

Adding an empty dependency list will cause it to get called just once on component did mount

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Called once on component mount");
}, []); // empty dependency list
```

Add a state to the dependency list to get called when state gets updated

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Called once on component mount and whenever count changes");
    console.log("Count: " + count);
}, [count]); // count as a dependency
```

Comment: You don't NEED to pass state in the useEffect. I was trying to explain how useEffect works so you know how to use it. You can either use it as a replacement for componentDidMount and/or as a listener/trigger for your state when it changes

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know how useEffect works. My question is related to the dependency array items.

Comment: Right, and my answer shows you the 3 different ways you can implement useEffect: no dependencies, an empty dependency list and a dependency list with state. The Reason Why You Pass Count As A Dependency is to monitor state and control how or if you want anything to happen when the state changes. useEffect has nothing to do with your UI.